# Storage location of meta description and keyword in Joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I wanted to update meta description and keywords with the joomla web interface. Unfortunately I get a Error 500 message when I trys to save changes.
Since I was not able to fix the error and I have to change the metadata quickly, I wanted to update them manually. Unfortunately I was not able to find the place where these values are stored. 

Can you please point me to the right file / db Table?

Thank you very much

Comment: You have to say which meta data you are talking about (site, article, contact etc)  but if it is global it is in your configuration.php file in the joomla root.

Comment: Elin, thank you very much. I was looking for the global meta description / keywords used for indexing by crawlers. This information is in configuration.php, as you correctly said. My problem was that I was reliying on the windows full text search, which simply did not return a result, although the keys I was searching for were correct.